# How to get first three words of a span class in PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, parsing, variables, dom

What is the way to get first three words of a span class using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).
Assuming source code of a fetched page is:

> Some Text `<span class="sos">` Good Better Best `<i> Some text</i> here</span>` Again some text here

Using php simple html dom parser we can get all content of a span class like this way:

```
$data = $html->find('span class="sos"');
```

so here, `$data` will declare full content of that span class.
What i wanna do is to get only the first three words of a span class in a new variable, so in this case it should be:

```
$new_data = 'Good Better Best';
```

How to do it?
PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser [Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you have commented @billyonecan post , sounds like your solution is:

```
$result = str_get_html($result);
foreach($html->find('.sos') as $xdat)
{
$x_des = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', strip_tags($xdat)), 0, 3));
$result = str_replace($x_des, ' ', $result);
$result = str_get_html($result);
}
```

change all variables according to your needs.

Comment: oh bro a million thanks to you. This is just what i was looking for, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use explode for this.

```
$data = $html->find('span class="sos"');
$breakdata = explode(" ",$data);
$firstThreeWords = array_slice($breakdata, 0, 3);

$final = implode(" ",$firstThreeWords); //Good Better Best
```

If you want to exclude the first three words,

```
$data = $html->find('span class="sos"');
$breakdata = explode(" ",$data);
$removeFirstThreeWords = array_slice($breakdata, 2);

$final = implode(" ",$removeFirstThreeWords ); //Some text here
```

Comment: Can obviously type faster than me :)

Comment: hahaha. You had the same solution i guess !! I was on keyboard from last 4 hours. My fingers are paining now..

Comment: great, but why its not working: foreach($result->find('span class="sos"') as $ftext) $output = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', strip_tags($ftext)), 0, 3)); $result = str_replace($output, '', $result); $result = str_get_html($result); here i wanna exclude every first three words of 'sos' span class from the fetched data. Thanks

Comment: Where is your foreach {} brackets ? Avoid writing scripts which are difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the above answer but uses `strip_tags` to remove HTML from the string beforehand.

```
$output = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', strip_tags($data)), 0, 3));
```

Comment: great, but why its not working: `foreach($result->find('span class="sos"') as $ftext)
$output = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', strip_tags($ftext)), 0, 3));
$result = str_replace($output, '', $result);
$result = str_get_html($result);`

Comment: here i wanna exclude every first three words of 'sos' span class from the fetched data.